# escape single quote in s3 select query

Tags: amazon-web-services, select, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

Sample data, stored in a file in S3.
As you can see the format of my data is one json per line

```
{"first":  "John", "last": "Smith"}
{"first":  "Mary", "last": "O'Hara"}
{"first":  "Mary", "last": "Oats"}
```

My ultimate objective is to query by the last name and using the like operator together with a user provided substring. So I go step by step from easy to difficult:

This query works and returns all rows:

```
select s.* from s3object s
```

Good! Let's continue.
The next query I tried works and returns, as expected, John Smith

```
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" = 'Smith'
```

The next step is to try by a substring of the surname. Let's find all persons whose last name starts with an "O".

```
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" like 'O%';
```

This works and returns the two Marys in my dataset.

The next step is the one that doesn't work. I want to find all users whose last name starts with an O and an apostrophe. This I can't make to work. I tried:

```
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" like 'O'%'
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" like 'O\'%'
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" like "O'%"
```

None of them works. How can I put a single quote (') inside a string literal in s3 select?

Comment: a little confused, could you give some expected data examples?

Comment: Simply use triple quotos """ for warp your query and use the single quoto as you wish.

Comment: Have you tried two single quotes? like 'O''%'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use two single quotes

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Test.testing
WHERE "last" = 'O''Hara';
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following query:

```
select s.* from s3object s where s."last" like 'O''%'
```

To escape a single quote, you need to specify one more single quote before it.